# How does a shell guess the PATH when spawned in an empty environment?

Tags: shell, unix, path, exec, environment-variables

Using the following code to run the `ls` command via `/bin/sh`nworks fine:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {
    execle("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls", (char*)NULL, envp);
}
```

However if I launch the shell in an empty environment, changing the `execle` line to read like this:

```
execle("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls", (char*)NULL, NULL);
```

It works too.

How does the shell know the path to `ls` even though I didn't pass any enviroment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets re-write your program as following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) 
{
        execle("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "ls", (char*)NULL, NULL);
        return 0;
}
```

Now, once you compile and run with [ltrace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ltrace), you'll find the following snippet in the output:

```
<... bsearch resumed> )                                                     = NULL
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
memcpy(0x0061cbe0, "/usr/local/sbin", 15)                                   = 0x0061cbe0
strcpy(0x0061cbf0, "ls")                                                    = 0x0061cbf0
__xstat64(1, "/usr/local/sbin/ls", 0x7fffb173e120)                          = -1
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
memcpy(0x0061cbe0, "/usr/local/bin", 14)                                    = 0x0061cbe0
strcpy(0x0061cbef, "ls")                                                    = 0x0061cbef
__xstat64(1, "/usr/local/bin/ls", 0x7fffb173e120)                           = -1
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
memcpy(0x0061cbe0, "/usr/sbin", 9)                                          = 0x0061cbe0
strcpy(0x0061cbea, "ls")                                                    = 0x0061cbea
__xstat64(1, "/usr/sbin/ls", 0x7fffb173e120)                                = -1
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
memcpy(0x0061cbe0, "/usr/bin", 8)                                           = 0x0061cbe0
strcpy(0x0061cbe9, "ls")                                                    = 0x0061cbe9
__xstat64(1, "/usr/bin/ls", 0x7fffb173e120)                                 = -1
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
memcpy(0x0061cbe0, "/sbin", 5)           
strcpy(0x0061cbe6, "ls")                                                    = 0x0061cbe6
__xstat64(1, "/sbin/ls", 0x7fffb173e120)                                    = -1
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
memcpy(0x0061cbe0, "/bin", 4)                                               = 0x0061cbe0
strcpy(0x0061cbe5, "ls")                                                    = 0x0061cbe5
__xstat64(1, "/bin/ls", 0x7fffb173e120)                                     = 0
strlen("ls")                                                                = 2
malloc(26)                                                                  = 0x025fa110
strcpy(0x025fa123, "ls")                                                    = 0x025fa123
realloc(NULL, 160)                                                          = 0x025fa140
fork()
```

As you can see, it's clearly looking for the right path before doing the fork() with `'/bin/ls'` which is the right path for `'ls'`. If there was `$PATH` variable given, `sh` would try those paths to find the location of `ls`. Since there is no `$PATH` provided in this case, plausible paths (e.g. `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin`) are tried nevertheless.

From `execle` man-page:

> If this PATH variable isn't specified, 
>   the default path is  set according to the 
>   _PATH_DEFPATH definition in , 
>   which is set to /usr/bin:/bin.

Comment: ...and the question was: why does it do that, when it was explicitely given *no* PATH variable?

Comment: @JB: The answer is (as the ltrace output points to), since there was no $PATH given, it looks through some plausible paths for the right location of 'ls' until it is found. Once the right path for 'ls' is found, it executes. The crude answer is: it is programmed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

From the `execle` man page:

`On  some other systems the default path (used when the environment does
 not contain the variable PATH) has the current working directory listed
 after  /bin  and /usr/bin, as an anti-Trojan-horse measure.  Linux uses
 here the traditional "current directory first" default path.`

So I guess your default path is `./:/bin:/usr/bin` if on Linux, `/bin:/usr/bin` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

`/bin/sh` sets a lot of variables on its own if they're undefined by the time it starts.  You can see the full list easily by running `env -i sh -c set`

For example, on my system:

```
$ env -i sh -c set
IFS='   
'
OPTIND='1'
PATH='/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'
PPID='2299'
PS1='$ '
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
PWD='/home/jb'
```

Note how this includes `PATH`.  Also note that PATH gets a status of variable only; it does not get promoted to the exported environment.  Cross-check that with `env -i sh -c env`.

```
$ env -i sh -c env
PWD=/home/jb
```

Comment: However If I set the execle's env to `char *env_init[] = {"USER=unknown", "PATH=\tmp", NULL};`, the `ls` command don't work.

Comment: @manutd, yes, they're only set if not already present.  Should have said that explicitely, editing...

Answer (score 1):

The reason this can work is that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) says this about `PATH`:

> If PATH is unset or is set to null, the path search is implementation-defined.

Your `/bin/sh` uses a default PATH for this case, which happens to include the directory with the `ls` executable. On my system (FreeBSD) I can inspect this with

```
$ strings -a /bin/sh | grep /bin:
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
```